# How can I display a JPG image so that a very low resolution displays first?

Tags: html, css, image, jpeg

I've noticed that on some sites, a very low resolution version of an image gets displayed underneath the final version before it's done loading, to give the impression that the page is loading faster. How is this done?

Answer (score 5):

This is called *progressive JPEG*. When you save a picture using a tool like Photoshop you need to specify you want to use this JPEG flavor.

I've found this Photoshop "Save for Web" dialog sample where you will find the whole *Progressive* option enabled:

[image]

Comment: that's it? there's no html to enable this?

Comment: @ensnare That's all. You need a browser supporting this, and this is every modern browser on the market :D

Comment: @ensnare I suppose if you're serving the images with PHP or something, you could transcode them on the fly to enable the progressive option. But it would be hard and certainly not help loading speed - unless you cache the resulting images, then it'd be feasible.

Comment: @MightyPork I really believe that encoding the pics in progressive format directly is the best option

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer What I had in mind is eg. user-submitted images, you don't have control over those.

Comment: @MightyPork Ah, I see. Then, obviously an on-the-fly conversion should work fine :D

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for depends upon the decoder and display software used. As noted, it occurs in progressive JPEG images. In that type of JPEG, the coefficients are broken down into separate scans.

The decode then needs to update the image in between decoding scans rather than just at the end of the image.

There was more need for this in the days of dial up modems. Unless the image is really large, it is usually faster just to wait and display the whole image.

If you are programming, the display software you use may have an option to update after scans.

Most libraries now use a model where you decode an image file stream into a generic image buffer. Then you display the image buffer. In this model, there generally is no place to display the images on the fly.

In short, you enable this by creating progressive JPEG images. Whether the image displays fading in dependents entire on what is used to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can batch *optimize* all your images using the [ImageMagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php) `convert` command like this:

```
convert -strip -interlace plane input.jpg output.jpg
```

You can use [these other options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interlace) instead of `plane`.

Or just prefix the output's filename with `PJPEG`

```
convert -strip input.jpg PJPEG:output.jpg
```

Along with a proper file search or filename expansion (e.g.):

```
for i in images/*; do
    # Your conversion command
done
```

The `strip` option is for stripping *any profiles or comments*, to make the conversion "*cleaner*". You may also want to set the [-quality](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) option to reduce the quality loss.